# Website Advertisement Software

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web, ads, currency

I am in the process of developing a website that will have advertisement on it.  I am looking at horizontal and vertical banner ads for now, but other styles may be used.  I have been developing the site using MVC4.

What I have found so far are the following...

- [phpAdsNew](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpadsnew/)
- [Google Adsense](https://www.google.com/adsense/)
- [Clicksor](http://www.clicksor.com/)
- [BidVertiser](http://www.bidvertiser.com/)

**Current Obstacles**

phpAdsNew is Open Source, but it would require me to manage all of the finances. I would like to keep this as maintenance free as I can.

Google Adsence has several restrictions on the type of advertisement and website content (no alcohol, ect).  Since my client is a beer brewer, it kind of chops my legs off for the main target.

**QUESTION**

Does anyone have any experience with these or other advertisement software that has been easy to use?

**Requirements**

I am fine with CPC, CPM, and other forms.  I would like to see a small script that I can place on my site and it runs remotely.  I prefer payment options via Pay-Pal, but checks are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with these networks as an advertiser so I can give opinion based on my experienced.

phpAdsNew - Is also called OpenX. Apparently they are closing their free ad-serving business.

Adsense - Since they don't allow your content, you can't work with them.

Clicksor - Huge fill rates but I'm not sure about their rates.

bidvertiser - Same as Clicksor.

There are alot factors that comes into play when deciding which adnetwork/software to use.

**First question is** : Do you have direct advertisers or are you looking for an adnetwork to help you sell your spots

**Second question is**: How much traffic do you have? Most big networks that offers better rates only works with huge publishers

In any case you can take a look at sites like http://www.adswiki.net/ where there is a list of adnetworks. Do check their history to see if they are paying their publishers on time.

Comment: Thank you Ryan.  I was beginning to think that I would not see any comments on this one.